# TPL Dataflow break LinkTo() during runtime

Tags: c#, concurrency, task-parallel-library, dataflow, tpl-dataflow

I have a `TransformManyBlock<Tin, Tout>` and during run time add consumers (ActionBlocks) through `LinkTo(...)`.

1. Is TransformManyBlock the correct data flow block to consume elements, transform them, and then output (same number elements output as input) to several consumers (each linked-to consumer consumes identical elements like a broadcast)? I deliberately do not chose a BroadCastBlock because it seems to be unable to transform elements similarly to a BufferBlock.
2. I like to know how I can unlink consumers (ActionBlocks here) during runtime? LinkTo() does not seem to provide such functionality as far as I can see.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1. `TransformManyBlock` is for transforming one item on the input into multiple items on the output, it has nothing to do with the number of consumers.

   If you want to perform the transformation separately for each target, then that's exactly what `cloningFunction` in `BroadcastBlock` is for.

   If you want to perform the transformation once and then send each target the same object, you can combine `TransformBlock` and `BroadcastBlock` by linking them together. The item will be transformed by the `TransformBlock`, and then sent to all targets by the `BroadcastBlock`.
2. The return value of [`LinkTo()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh194692) is:

   > An `IDisposable` that, upon calling `Dispose`, will unlink the source from the target.

   This is exactly what you need. Just store the value returned from `LinkTo()` and then `Dispose()` it when necessary.

Comment: is BroadcastBlock the only block that can accomplish this? I find it adds overhead adding it because it does nothing other than just cloning (applied to my example). I was hoping to be able to find something that may not add such overhead. 2. Exactly what I was looking for, thanks.

Comment: Is `BroadcastBlock` the only built-in block that sends each message to all its targets? Yeah. (`WriteOnceBlock` does that too, but it's very limited.) If the overhead of `BroadcastBlock` really is too much for you, then you will have to create your own block that combines `TransformBlock` and `BroadcastBlock`, or something like that.

Comment: Yes sorry, I was away on vacation...thank you Svick for this answer.

Comment: Thanx for the IDisposable unlinking tip.

Comment: Depending on why you are breaking links, you may want to consider the DataflowLinkOptions.MaxMessages which will automatically break the link when the target number of messages has been reached.